# Writing htaccess that points to a file in the sub-directory

Tags: .htaccess, yii

I have a order page in the following path

```
https://example.com/backend/web/order
```

And I want to display it as

```
https://example.com/order
```

What should be the htaccess code (please let me know of every step if possible so I can learn also). Where should I place the htaccess file? Inside the backend folder or the root folder.

Comment: I edited to change "sub-domain" to "sub-directory".  A subdomain is like `foo.example.com` and you don't actually have one of those in your question, I think you mean "sub-directory."

Comment: How is a request for `/backend/web/order` currently being routed? What script handles this request? What other directives do you have in the `.htaccess` file? Do you have multiple `.htaccess` files in subdirectories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change  `https://example.com/backend/web/order` to `https://example.com/order` you can use the following rule in htaccess in your root folder :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^order /back-end/web/order [L]
```

The rule above makes it possible to access your old URL as  `http://example.com/order` .

Comment: The answer is working fine for me, but there's only one thing that when we are targeting the /web/order in the htaccess, it should show the order page, but it's showing the main page instead. I don't if I explained it right

Comment: It sounds like you have other rewrite rules that are conflicting.  What other rules are you using?  Where in your .htaccess file did you place the rule (top, middle or bottom?)

Comment: A rewrite like this is unlikely to work since `/backend/web/order` itself is not a valid end-point and needs to be further rewritten to be useful (using a front-controller). So, depending on how the routing is managed, the back-end script is likely only going to see `/order` (the requested URL), not `/backend/web/order` (the rewritten URL). In short, it depends on the rest of the application. (A "workaround" would be to implement this as an external redirect, but then `/order` won't be "displayed" in the browser's URL bar and you should avoid linking to URLs internally that redirect.)

Comment: "The answer is working fine for me ... but it's showing the main page instead." - That doesn't sound "fine" to me? "when we are targeting the `/web/order`" - do you mean `/order` or `/backend/web/order`?